# how create array of arrays of unequal depth, holding integers only (Android)

Tags: multidimensional-array, arraylist

How do I create an array that looks like this:

```
[[1,2,[[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4]],[15,20],35,[2,1]],
 [2,2,[[6,6,6,6,6],[1,2,3,4,5]],[30,15],45,[2,1]],
 [2,2,[[6,6,6,6,6],[1,2,3,4,5]],[30,15],45,[2,1]],
 [2,2,[[6,6,6,6,6],[1,2,3,4,5]],[30,15],45,[2,1]],
 ...]
```

So a 4-dimensional array, holding integer values only, and with array's within array's but of unequal depth.

[edited]
Using named elements I would get this declaration:

```
// containerarray spelersSpel:
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>> spelersSpel_ = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>>();

// holding:
// first-level element of spelersSpel:
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> spelerSpel = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();

// holding:

// first element of spelerSpel:
private int spelerNummer;

// second element of spelerSpel:
private int spelerBeurtNummer;

// third element of spelerSpel:
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>spelerBeurtenWorpenScore = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
// holding:
private ArrayList<Integer>spelerBeurtWorpenScore = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// holding:
private int spelerBeurtWorpScore;

// fourth element of spelerSpel:
private ArrayList<Integer>spelerBeurtenTotaal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// fifth element of spelerSpel:
private ArrayList<Integer>spelerBanen = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// holding:
private int spelerBaan;
```

and putting values in them like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    spelerBaan = 2;
    spelerBanen.add(spelerBaan);
    spelerSpel.add(spelerBanen);
```

However then I'm still having a problem, on the last line, adding array spelerBanen to spelerSpel, because spelerSpel expects EVERY (first-level) element now to be a two-dimensional array, which spelerBanen isn't. How to solve that? I could think of using a dummy placeholder, like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>dummy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
dummy.add(spelerBanen);         
spelerSpel.add(dummy);
```

but that doesn't seem to be a great solution to me either?

[edited]
My idea would be to change the declaration of spelerSpel to:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> spelerSpel = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>(5);
```

so with 'fixed' length of 5. and then:

```
spelerBaan = 2;
spelerBanen.set(0, spelerBaan);
spelerSpel.get(0).set(0,spelerBanen);
spelersSpel.add(spelerSpel);
```

I would still be stuck with an array holding a lot of 'dummy' values but I can't figure out how to do it better.

Comment: What language are you using? In JavaScript, you're already done.

Comment: Java (for an Android 2.2 app)

Comment: I certainly do not want to read that code later... Every developer will need to know very precisely what the values in the array mean! I believe on the long term you would be better off creating a class to hold that kind of non-homogenous information.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code an example of 4D array and a main method to display all the values.

```
public class SampleClass {
    static final int arrays[][][][] = {
            { { { 0, 2528 }, { 12, 25 }, { 25, 258 } },
                    { { 25, 345 }, { 345, 345 } } },
            { { { 4654, 234234 }, { 23434, 852 } },
                    { { 7897, 56345 }, { 3422, 57 }, { 98889, 234234 } } },
            { { { 545, 45645 }, { 45645, 3232 }, { 5252, 65465 } },
                    { { 45645, 234234 }, { 6451, 68678 } } },
            {
                    { { 789798, 34234 }, { 234234, 23423 } },
                    { { 23423, 234234 }, { 345345, 456456 }, { 5757, 800000 } },

            } };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < arrays[i][j].length; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < arrays[i][j][k].length; l++) {

                        System.out.println(arrays[i][j][k][l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you are looking for same or you are looking for other thing. +1 expected.

Comment: I agree with Jean and in one way or another that is indeed what I want to do. E.g. the whole array is a 'spelersSpel', the first line (first index in first dimension) is a (3-dimensional array) 'spelerSpel' (one s less), the array [15,20] is a 'spelerBeurtenTotaal' etc: every item represents a piece of information that must be referenced by a name. Putting them together in an array is intended to be the way to glue all the objects together and make them adressable.

Comment: Therefore ('Innovation') it would make sense to me if I could address the 15 in the 15,20 pair as spelersSpel[3,0], not as spelersSpel[0,3,0,0].

Still: how should I do that (what would that class look like? and how to create an array holding these arrays or integer values? 

Moreover, about half of these (sub)arrays must be expandable.

Comment: I added declaration of multidimensional ArrayLists and usage and the problems I'm having with that solution to the original question, please refer.